# WPF Application - Rendering performances

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, rendering, hardware-acceleration

I am currently developing an application for Windows XP, 7 and 8.
To test this application, I use two computers.

When hardware acceleration is enabled:

- On the first computer: the application is very fluid
- On the second computer: the application is very slow

When hardware acceleration is disabled:

- On the first computer: the application is a bit slow
- The second computer: the application is a bit slow

So, I would like to disable hardware acceleration based on the computer on which the application is launched. For that, I am currently using the following code:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //Try to improve performances
        int renderingTier = (RenderCapability.Tier >> 16);
        if(renderingTier < 2)
        {
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that both computers have RenderingTier = 2. This is why I would like to replace

```cs
        if(renderingTier < 2)
        {
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        }
```

by

```cs
        if(renderingTier < 2 || Something())
        {
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        }
```

Can you help me to find the function  "Something()" ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you really come to a conclusion that it runs slow because of hardware acceleration based on only 2 PCs?

Comment: Check out http://www.wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html, specifically #4: _Prevent Software Rendering. The use of transparent windows by setting AllowsTransparency to true or using old BitmapEffects can cause WPF to render the UI in software on Windows XP, which is much slower._

Comment: Thank you Tseng for this link. In fact, I have already seen this post. My application does not have BitmapEffects and the AllowsTransparency property is set to false.

Comment: @MikeEason, No, actually I have tested the application on more PCs. I just wanted to simplify the situation by presenting it that way

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hardcoding it, why not let the user decide if he/she wants to use hardware or software rendering? Just include a setting in your application that the user can toggle.

It simplifies your task, and, most importantly, you don't have to hard-code your criteria for choosing one or the other.

Apart from that: It might also help to find out ***why*** its rendering performance is slow, and see if you can improve it, before building in rendering control.

Comment: In fact, I would like to do both: provide an option to disable hardware acceleration and also provide an option to detect the best rendering mode.
About the performances, the application is a bit slow when hardware acceleration is disabled due to some animations I use. I would like not to remove them if possible.

Comment: If you want to detect the best rendering mode, then I would just base it on the reported `RenderCapabilities.Tier`. Apparently this what Microsoft considers to be a relevant means of determining what render mode to use. It consults various DirectX and video card attributes (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't presume to know better than Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Reduce CPU Consumption for WPF Animations according to computer performance
    /// WPF draws animations at 60 frames per second. You can reduce this to a lower optimal rate, resulting in less CPU usage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fps"></param>
    private void Optimize()
    {
        int displayTier = (RenderCapability.Tier >> 16);

        if (displayTier < 2) // No hardware acceleration
        {
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
            Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 24 });
        }
        else // Supports hardware acceleration
        {
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.Default;
            Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 60 });
        }          
    }
```